# On-Premises equivalent of VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking

A lot of examples for AWS and I'm confident others, use the AWS concept of a VPC in part to give some degree of security. The idea being that it can be set up to only allow traffic from certain ports and even certain IP addresses.  What it does however give, is a zone of defined traffic.

What did people do for on premise installations before the cloud? Somewhere someone is probably even doing something still on their own computer network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Amazon VPC is a **virtualized network**.

Traditional physical networks consist of routers, switches and firewalls.

Even physical networks use virtualized networks, providing "VLANS" such as Production, Testing and Development virtual networks all across the same physical network.

An Amazon VPC maps very closely to "real-world" networks, except that they are **easier to configure** and don't require any cabling. VPC maintains the concepts of public and private subnets, route tables and inter-network connections.

Once capability of an Amazon VPC that does *not* exist in physical networks is the concept of a **Security Group**, which is a **firewall for each individual resources**. Traditional networks use firewall devices to restrict traffic travelling between subnets (similar to VPC NACLs), but Security Groups add firewall function at the resource-level, such as on an Amazon EC2 instance or Amazon RDS database. This adds considerably more security capabilities that available in normal network.

Amazon VPCs can also be deployed via API calls or AWS CloudFormation templates, **allowing a whole network to be deployed from a script**. This is similar to what can be accomplished with VMware virtual networks.